# Issues with httpd config to proxy most requests to tomcat

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, amazon-elb, proxypass

I have had some difficulty in getting the following working in Apache:

We have an apache/tomcat instance sitting behind an AWS ELB. The ELB is doing SSL termination so we have a redirect on the server to handle this.

I need `/health` to be reachable on http for the ELB health check to work.

I need to send everything that isn't `/` or `theme` to tomcat i.e. `/foo` proxies to `localhost:8080/foo`.

I've tried a few variations of the below config using mod_proxy and/or mod_rewrite but I cannot seem to get this to work properly so would appreciate any pointers.

```
<Location /health>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/health ttl=1
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/health
</Location>

<Location ~ "^/(.+)">
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(health|theme)/
  RewriteRule . http://localhost:8080/$1 [P]
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/$1
</Location>

<Location />
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/health
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
   RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
</Location>
```

Tomcat is listening on port 8080 using plain http.

Answer (score 1):

I have Tomcat listening for ajp on port 8009. Apart from the other advantages, this allows the same virtual hosts to be defined in both servers' configurations, so the requests (which default to port 80) reach Apache first, where I have several virtual hosts defined. Reverse-proxy rules then decide which requests to forward to various other hosts (either remote or other local virtual hosts), serve content from a DocumentRoot or forward to Tomcat via ajp. When mod_proxy_ajp forwards requests to Tomcat, by default they keep their hostnames, which allows Tomcat to direct them to different webapps with matching virtual hostnames that I've defined in server.xml.

The following examples aren't doing exactly what you've described, but I hope they show the flexibility available with virtual hosts in both server configurations and allow you to come up with configurations that meets your needs.

/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.local.website.com
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
#   proxy specific paths to other virtual hosts
    ProxyPass         /articles  http://a.local.website.com/articles
    ProxyPassReverse  /articles  http://a.local.website.com/articles
    ProxyPass         /entertainment  http://b.local.website.com/entertainment
    ProxyPassReverse  /entertainment  http://b.local.website.com/entertainment
#   send everything else to tomcat via ajp on port 8009
    ProxyPass         /  ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  ajp://localhost:8009/
</VirtualHost>
```

$CATALINA_HOME/server.xml

```
<Host name="my.local.website.com" appBase="temp" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
    prefix="website_access." suffix=".log" pattern="common"/>
</Host>
```